# Why does pd.to_numeric not work with large numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a large number in a string, like `'555555555555555555555'`. One could choose to convert it to an int, float or even a numpy float:

```
int('555555555555555555555')
float('555555555555555555555')
np.float('555555555555555555555')
```

However, when I use the pandas function `pd.to_numeric`, things go wrong:

```
pd.to_numeric('555555555555555555555')
```

With error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1173, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Integer out of range.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path_to_conda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-6a735441ab7b>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_numeric('555555555555555555555')
  File "C:\path_to_conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 133, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1185, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Integer out of range. at position 0
```

What's going wrong? Why can't pandas `to_numeric` handle larger values? Are there any use cases why you would use `pd.to_numeric` instead of functions like `np.float`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your number is larger that the maximum size of an integer that your system is capable of saving:

```
In [4]: import sys

In [5]: sys.maxsize
Out[5]: 9223372036854775807

In [6]: 555555555555555555555 > sys.maxsize
Out[6]: True
```

Here is part of [*the source code*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9ad1e00c5c70b4446f2af5bea9089ca3312a3eb5/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1889) that raises the `ValueError`:

```
if not (seen.float_ or as_int in na_values):
    if as_int < oINT64_MIN or as_int > oUINT64_MAX:
        raise ValueError('Integer out of range.')
```

As you can see, because your number is not a float it treats it as an integer and checks if the number is in the proper range `oINT64_MIN, oUINT64_MAX`. If you've passed a float number instead it'd gave you the proper result:

```
In [9]: pd.to_numeric('555555555555555555555.0')
Out[9]: 5.5555555555555554e+20
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why doesn't pandas convert this to float instead.

Comment: @ayhan Because that's not a correct way to deal with this. When the user passes a certain type they need to be sure that the function will treat them based on that type. If it isn't so there should be some way to specify that.

Comment: I am not sure that's the reason. Compare `pd.to_numeric(['1.', '555555555555555555555'])` to `pd.to_numeric(['555555555555555555555', '1.'])` for example. pandas is happily converting to float in the first one but raising an error in the second one.

Comment: @ayhan I think based on this [line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9ad1e00c5c70b4446f2af5bea9089ca3312a3eb5/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1795) it will assume implicitly about the types of the array by the type of the first value in the array

Comment: @ayhan This is clearly a different case. Here you have multiple types and deciding that which one should has has a higher precedence is a different problem than when you're dealing with one input. It seems that they've decided to go with the order but I think that's wrong. There should be more complicated ways of giving precedence to a list items.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are both right but basing this on the order leads to very strange results: `pd.to_numeric(['555555555555555555555', 'abc'], errors='coerce')` vs `pd.to_numeric(['abc', '555555555555555555555'], errors='coerce')`. I'll be more cautious when using `to_numeric` in the future.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd If you exceed the maxsize of an int, why does `int('555555555555555555555')` work and `pd.to_numeric('555555555555555555555')` not?

Comment: @Guido Because integers in python are not bounded but in pandas since it's mostly customized for working with dataframes, matrices, etc. it's less likely to work with an standalone integer object. Hence, it's better to put a boundary on integers in order to prevent the data from causing memory leaks.